# How to fetch TestCategory name for which the TestMethod has been invoked?

Tags: c#, mstest, azure-pipelines

I am trying to fetch TestCategory name of a particular TestMethod in MSTest for which the TestMethod has been run.

If a TestMethod has multiple TestCategory for which particular TestCategory was the method invoke ?

I am using below code which gets all the TestCategories of the Method, but how to find for which particular category the method was invoked.

```
[TestMethod, TestCategory("Reg"), TestCategory("Smoke"), TestCategory("Sanity"), TestCategory("PathTest")]
public void TestMethod_testCatetory()
{
       var method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
        foreach (var attribute in (IEnumerable<TestCategoryAttribute>)method
                    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestCategoryAttribute), true))
          {
                foreach (var category in attribute.TestCategories)
                {
                     Console.WriteLine(category);
                }
         }
}
```

From cmd this will be invoke using below command

```
C:\VSTest.Console.exe LocationOfDLL /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=Smoke"
```

Is it possible to fetch TestCategory is Smoke which as used to invoke the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t get current category in the test method code directly. 
You can read the value from RunSettings file (`TestContext.Properties[xxx]`) and override the parameter during the test, simple steps:

1. Define a variable to store category
2. Specify filters with that variable in Test Filter criteria input box of Visual Studio test task
3. Specify parameters in Override TestRun Parameters input box of Visual Studio Test task

There is a blog that can help you: [Supplying Run Time Parameters to Tests](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/09/04/supplying-run-time-parameters-to-tests/)

Comment: For other looking for answer,  this work only when the test is ran from build and release not from test explorer or cmd.  In cmd there is no option to Override TestRun Parameters.

Comment: @Vincent Yes, not apply for test explorer.